# Delay jQuery Mobile transition in order to hide embedded Youtube video

Tags: youtube, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to create a site which will display an embedded YouTube clip on one of the pages.

My problem is that when the user tries to navigate to another page, the embedded object remains "over" the page whilst the transition plays. The result is that the video appears over the 2nd page for a split second and it doesn't look good.

I've tried using `.hide()` on the video when a link is clicked and also tried creating a timeout but to no avail - can someone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I wasn't capturing the correct event - I was checking for click when I needed to bind to a 'tap' event like so:

```
$("#link").live('tap',function(){
   $("#video").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove the actual video from the page; this also happens on every browser, because Flash usually appears over all other content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as it turns out .hide() works fine, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'pagebeforehide' event to remove the flash video, however you can also use youtube's iframe embed method to show the video rather than an embed tag (I have not had problems with persistant flash objects using the iframe method).

```
$('#youtube_page_id').live('pagebeforehide', function () {
    $('#youtube_embed_id').remove();
});
```

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
```

Another benefit to using the iframe method with youtube is that youtube will detect the device that the user is on and display the proper type of video. For instance if a user is on an iPhone then youtube will display a HTML5 video rather than a Flash video.

Comment: Whilst the iframe solution does indeed solve the problem of showing/hiding the video - its not as elegant as the embedded flash object. For example, the video doesn't scale like the flash option and also displays the video title as an overlay which causes the player to look very cramped on a mobile device. Additionally, the behaviour seems erratic - sometimes the video plays as html5 video instantly, other times the mobile youtube site is loaded. Thanks for your reply all the same :-)